# Filtering Hour of Day such that I get the next 48 hours using Regex in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I am trying to create a custom report in Google Analytics to see conversions of an email 48 hours after it was sent.

To filter the specific email, I am filtering UTM parameters. Now I am not sure how to filter Hour of Day (or maybe Hour of Hour Index) so that the report shows me the first 48 hours related to the UTM parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Hour of Day** as secondary dimension in standard report or in a custom report.

```
2019091223 --> YYYYMMDDHH
```

Where **DD** is the day and **HH** is the hour of the day.

To filter an interval you can do something like this in advanced filter whit Hour of Day secondary dimension selected:

[image]

Comment: I have used **Hour of Day** as a dimension. My question is how to filter **Hour of Day** such that I only see data for the first 48 hours related to a specific **Ad Content**. I assume it is done with regex but I am not sure how.

Comment: In the advanced filters there is no regex for that dimension. I modified the post above by adding a screenshot to show you how you can do it.